# How do I prevent my manager from abusing a contract specification that breaches my privacy?

Tags: ethics, software-development, security, netherlands

I'm employed as a software developer. In my country the employer is not allowed to monitor your activities due to privacy laws. However, due to the nature of some of our clients, our company is allowed to do this due to security reasons. It's specifically stated in my contract that the company can monitor our network activity for security reasons. I accepted this when I applied for the job as I can see why this could be important.

However, my manager has a lot of trouble managing the employees and tends to cause more problems. Our boss seems to like him so there's not much we can do about that. This makes addressing this problem to a position above my manager less likely to have an impact.

My manager often does not know what to do so he tries to make sure we're always working hard on our jobs. This in itself is not a problem. But the methods he uses are unethical. He uses software to forcefully take over our computers from a distance and browses through what we're doing, what browser tabs we have open etc.

While the contract says the employer is allowed to breach a certain degree of privacy due to security reasons, I feel like he's abusing this to an extreme extent and for the wrong reasons.

How can I prevent my manager from abusing this exception in the work environment?

Comment: Walk to your Manager and say I noticed that you took over my Computer. Can i help you with something?

Comment: @RaoulMensink This has been done many times, but he will keep doing this and occasionally vaguely bring these occurance up in an employer review. This happens with every single employee in the company. When this happens it got to the point where it indicates we can have a coffee break. as we cant use our pc's for that moment.

Comment: IANAL, but in your Country a contract may not overrule specific privacy laws and I think what your manager is doing is breaking that. They may ask the ínformation or even demand it, but as far as I know you still Need to give it.

Comment: @RaoulMensink I believe this company contacted the local government department to have it specially requested to have this added to the contract. So this is a very rare exception. The main intentions were to monitor the network to prevent any leaks. While it's unlikely that this would include abruptly taking over computers without consent, it may not specify this in the contract. Hense why I'm looking for other ways to handle this situation. The last resort is obviously leaving the company or just suck it up. I'm just curious what I could do before resorting to that.

Comment: the local government has no such power, but this is a common thing in our country sadly enough.

Comment: Not long enought to justify an answer, but at you re place, I d try to find a solution that doesn t break my workflow and doesn t block the manager access, then propose that solution with the argument that breaking the workflow can be very hard to recover.

Comment: Unplug the Ethernet cable. Turn Wifi off. Call your security people "someone is hacking into my computer".

Comment: Is this your personal machine or the company's? Logging and monitoring network traffic is one thing, a normal thing within companies, but complete takeover of your computer tells me that it's either the company's equipment or you agreed to a clause in the contract which resulted in additional software being installed on your personal computer.

Comment: Some of my best, most valuable, most productive work has been done sitting where I could stare out of a window with a pad of paper and a pencil. A morning thinking through a design that way may save many days of programming effort and result in a better program. Monitoring computer activity is an ineffective way of monitoring productivity.

Comment: "When this happens it got to the point where it indicates we can have a coffee break. as we cant use our pc's for that moment." - so *switch off your PC*, and then take the coffee break.

Comment: You might want to start looking around at possible other jobs. You apparently aren't happy about your current situation, so leaving might be an improvement. At the very least some orientation might end up dealing a hand of cards you like.

Comment: It may be legal to monitor your network access for security reasons, that doesn't make it legal (in the Netherlands) to use any information gained for performance reviews, with the exception of "strafbare feiten", i.e. legally punishable offenses like hacking, intentionally damaging company property or watching/spreading child porn.

Comment: If this bothers you sufficiently, you can try to find a job elsewhere which doesn't have that contract clause, or that is willing to negotiate on that clause. It's your responsibility to consider all the implications before putting your signature on the paper.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Monitoring Internet access and employee acitivity on security breakpoints for security reasons is prudent and necessary, and thats why it's allowed.

Another thing you mention, which is not only not necessary, but also highly unethical and I'd hazard also illegal (IANAL, consult a lawyer specialising in employment law for this) is that he has remote access to your computer. This means that he can do stuff under YOUR identity - stuff that YOU would get blamed for in audits or criminal investigations.

You need to bring this specific concern (the taking over your computer) to your boss asap. If he doesn't cooperate, bring it to your boss's boss. If he doesn't cooperate either, get a lawyer, and go looking for a new job.

There are also much better and less intrusive ways of finding out internet traffic and/or history without taking over the computer.

Comment: This is a very good point. Doing this alot and making it known also causes the company problems in the long run as it taints the evidence. Now instead of one suspect all the managers are suspects also.  So its in the best interests of the company to not do this unless the system is entirely passive.

Comment: This is scary. How is it even possible that in an environment which deals with security-sensitive information like this, someone can take over a computer just like that? How do you know that this capability is restricted to your manager, and not just anybody on the Internet can take over your computer? How do you even know it *is* your manager taking over your computer and not an attacker? Would you even be able to distinguish between the two? You should treat the machine as compromised, and do whatever your disaster recovery plan says in such a situation (probably isolate it and report to IT)

Comment: While this will not be the approach that I will take with this situation. I do believe this is the best answer to my question. and will therefor accept it. It does give a good to know perspective to the situation.

Comment: Taking over your desktop to see what you're doing is not really a security check but just an excuse. I don't see how a manager who taken over your computer would prevent security violations? What would he check? If you posted company secrets? It makes more sense to check security violations on a proxy server that can be proven. Otherwise there's nothing that says the manager didn't do it to make the employee look bad. Or even a disgruntled employee who happened to know the rdp ip addresses/passwords.

Comment: @Dan If you have more to add, I encourage you to edit it in. I made the post CW.

Comment: Kick up a stink and look for a new job.... might get the OP fired? I would also think that disclosing their security policies to a third party might be illegal as well. But all in all a reasonable answer for some locales.

Comment: If they know what they're doing (good chance they don't), then the remote control functionality is (should be!) logged and audited, in which case it's not a security problem by itself.  YMMV on privacy, of course.

Comment: @Kevin Another aspect is that randomly losing control of your computer is really devastating for productivity as a dev. I can't speak for everyone, but when im "In the zone" of efficient coding and someone just interrupts me, thats a good 20-30 min of time to get back there.

Comment: @Magisch: Yes, you should not do this to devs.  But it could make some amount of sense for something more interrupt-driven and/or boring that happens to involve computers.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, but then, actually, for remote controlling reasons (needing to do something from someone's PC while they're gone) and not for security or monitoring reasons. As I said, there are tons of solutions to monitor everything that happens on a pc that dont depend on remote control.

Comment: I'd be weary of bringing this up to the boss, it may be considered to be accusing the boss of being unscrupulous - bring it up to whoever is in charge of security in the form of "how do I document what *I" don't do on my computer"

Comment: It always amazes me what can happen on some workplaces. I wouldn't ever think about this being possible.

Comment: The manager does not have remote access to the OP's computer.  The manager has remote access to the companies computer.

Answer (score 15):

If security is such a concern that your company has special contract terms related to it, there should be a network security group to look after it. Because security is a major concern, they may have more organizational power and influence than you do.

It might be worth discussing your concerns with them.

They have an interest in people not accessing computers they do not need to access to do their job. The more people with access to information the greater the risk of leaks and the harder it is to track them down. Your manager's ability to "take over" a lot of other computers is a security risk. Breaking in to your manager's account would be a doorway to many computers.

They also have an interest in the security-related contract provision not being misused, because misuse might make it harder to preserve and enforce the provision.

Answer (score 7):

> He uses software to forcefully take over our computers from a distance
>   and browses through what we're doing, what browser tabs we have open
>   etc,.

*Who watches the watchman?*

Your manager can do whatever he wants on your computer, in your current session, with your digital identity. How safe is that? Is the manager's computer provably secured against malware? Is the manager provably competent to not do anything harmful, for which *you* would be blamed because the audit shows *your* account responsible?

Comment: This is not really an answer it is just asking for more information with out actually providing any solution.

Comment: I think this *is* an answer, @Chad. It's phrased as a rhetorical question, but it functions as an answer. It raises concerns which the OP can then raise in turn.

Comment: Depending on the remote control configuration and software in question, logs of actions taken by the manager while he/she is logged-in should show as originating from a remote user, and would therefore be distinct from OP's digital identity.  That said, these actions would still originate from OP's computer and IP address so liability could be an issue if the people looking into any indiscretions are not thorough.

Answer (score 6):

He's not abusing it, he has the capability which you have expressly given permission for, and he's using it. I can see how this would be annoying, but it's something you could learn to live with and will probably have to.

Using it just to keep employees on their toes isn't the best use of the capability. It could for instance be very disruptive when people are deep in working on something complex. So unless it's mandated by company policy it appears your manager has too much time on his hands. I have seen some pretty strict company policies in my time though, in which the manager is held responsible for any breaches, where monitoring of activity is done on multiple levels, mostly without the employee noticing.

But there's nothing you can do about it that won't make you seem guilty of trying to conceal something. Even arguing that it is interfering with your work isn't a great idea. Because even a mediocre manager is well aware of that fact.

Possibly your only realistic recourse without trying to organise a mutiny is to ask people who have been there longer and presumably have more knowledge whether it's a company policy or not. At least that way you might get some information without rocking the boat with your manager.

Comment: I'm quite worried that this is indeed the case. It is as you said, very disruptive. I'm not worried about the activities he may find, but it certainly bothers me and may put un-needed stress on the work. I hope to find other answers that may help me find a way to handle this situation before simply sucking it up. But this was a very helpful answer so far.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion. There's a difference between monitoring and interference. It seems like the manager is doing a remote desktop session which interrupts the dev's workflow. That's a legitimate grievance the OP can raise with the manager. They're more than welcome to snoop around their computers, all the OP's asking is for them to be discreet.

Comment: On the other hand this could be a deliberate decision on the manager's part, doing some kind of `you are being watched` mind-trick.

Comment: @rath I specifically took that in to account in my answer "Using it just to keep employees on their toes isn't the best use of the capability. It could for instance be very disruptive when people are deep in working on something complex."

Comment: He is abusing his capability.  Permission was given for these capabilities for a specific purpose, the manager is using it for a different reason.  It's certainly abusing and might even be flat out a breach of contract (depending on the actual wording).

Comment: @Migz - But it is his business or at least he has been hired to manage that business.  unless he violates your privacy by sharing personal information he found through that snooping there is likely little you can do.  The government is not responsible for making sure businesses are run effectively.  And it could be argued that this is the most effective way the manager knows. (I agree its bad but the argument can be made)

Comment: @Chad: Are you American?  Europeans tend to take privacy *much* more seriously.  Governments are not responsible for making sure businesses are run effectively, but they *are* responsible for making sure privacy laws are followed.  Just because the OP has given permission for monitoring for one purpose does *not* give permission for monitoring to occur *unless it is for that purpose*.

Comment: @MartinBonner - I am not saying what he did was right, just that there is little he can do about it lacking proof that the information is being misused

Comment: @Chad: He probably doesn't need proof it is being misused.  The manager probably has to show the information is *not* being misused (and gathering it for anything other than the specified reason, is "misuse").

Comment: @MartinBonner - You should make that into an answer then.  That is not my understanding of how it works but I will admit to not having the best understanding of the European legal systems

Answer (score 6):

**In my view, companies have a right to know what employees are doing.**  They are, after all, paying the employees to do certain things, and it is reasonable to want the ability to verify whether the employees are actually doing these things. There is nothing *inherently* unethical about using tools to monitor what employees are doing on company time.

**Aggressive monitoring is not necessarily a great idea, as it communicates a lack of trust in employees and may interfere with their work.**  Certainly what the boss is doing in this case doesn't seem advisable.  It seems disruptive, while also harming employee morale.  But I would argue that he is only guilty of being an ineffective manager, not unethical (the question of legality in this jurisdiction aside).

**Whether they are illegal in your specific jurisdiction is a much narrower question (which we can't answer, not being lawyers and not even knowing what country's laws apply).**  I personally find it mind-boggling that a company monitoring employee use of its own resources can be illegal due to "privacy", but there you go.

So, what to do?

- **I would not object on the basis of my privacy rights being invaded.**  Since I don't think that I have such a privacy right in the workplace (whatever the law says).  Plus, "How dare you intrude on my rights by checking whether I am working!" just doesn't sound great, even if you have a legal basis for saying that.
- **A *business argument* against the monitoring would be the strongest basis for objecting.**  You have a much stronger case if you can argue that the monitoring is harming the company in some way.

  - **If it is interrupting your work, raise the reduction in productivity as an issue.** "This is costing us money" is usually the best argument you can make, particularly if you can back it up with evidence.
  - **You could also raise the morale issue, but it is trickier.**  You could tell your boss "This monitoring is making employees unhappy, because we want to feel that we are valued and trusted", or some such argument.  However, with this argument your motives are likely to come across as self-interested, even if you are stating it is for the good of the company.  "Give us what we want so that morale will be good" will often be heard simply as "Give us what we want."

Comment: "In my country the employer is not allowed to monitor your activities due to privacy laws".  So in OP the employer does not have the right to know what the employee is doing.

Comment: @Taemyr and dan, for what its worth, germany is like that. To monitor activity beyond outgoing internet access logs (and even that needs written consent prior for which the employee can not be not hired or terminated for refusing) monitoring employees is generally illegal in that way. The only exemptions from this are court warrants or probable cause, which involved prior incidents and a written consent from the employees.

Comment: @Taemyr I understand that but I was trying to make a distinction between what I view as ethical and what the law in the jurisdiction states.  I view such a law as unreasonable, and I don't think there is anything unethical in the abstract with an employer monitoring use of employee time.

Comment: @dan1111 Then you where presenting your personal opinion as a fact.

Comment: @Taemyr the OP is asking for opinions about what they should do, and all answers are assumed to be opinion, surely?  We don't need to start every sentence with "In my opinion..."

Comment: @dan1111: Your opening statement "Companies have a right to know what employees are doing" read to me as a statement of law, not of ethics.  If you had started it "In my view ...", it would have been clear it was ethics, not law.

Comment: @MartinBonner fair enough, I have made such an edit.

Answer (score 3):

IANAL but to me take over your PC is a stretch from "monitor your network activity for security reasons". It has gone beyond monitor, security, and  network in my opinion.

Remotely take over a PC to the level you are locked out is clearly beyond monitor by any reasonable interpretation of the word in my opinion.

> It indicates we can have a coffee break. As we can't use our pc's for
>   that moment.

Shutting you down is beyond *monitor* and is just plain not productive.

If a principal comes to classroom to *monitor* a teacher and takes the chalk from the teachers hand and goes through the desk that is beyond monitor.

Can you do much?  Maybe not.  Is it really worth the battle of trying to get it shut down?  He will still be an ineffective manager, with a boss that supports him, and you are the one that took away his favorite tool. The path of least resistance is to just accept it.